# Basic bar plot using matplotlib

Tags: python, dataframe, matplotlib, plot, bar-chart

I've created a very basic dataframe, but as I'm a newbie I'm struggling with creating a bar plot using the matplotlib.pyplot library.

Here is the dataframe:

```
d = {'Movies' : pd.Series([3560, 12354], index = ['Netflix', 'Prime Video']),
     'Shows' : pd.Series([1925, 2132], index = ['Netflix', 'Prime Video'])
    }

df = pd.DataFrame(d)
df
```

Is it possible to have 'Streaming Service' on the x-axis (i.e. Netflix and Prime Video) and 'Number' on the y-axis (with different coloured bars for movies vs shows)?

Comment: `df.plot.bar()`?

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/visualization.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is as simple as [`df.plot.bar()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.bar.html):

[image]